# Where does H5P store content in moodle?

Tags: plugins, moodle

This might be a very trivial question ?
I am a beginner with LMS and interactive contents.
I am using H5P Quizzes using H5P interactive content plugin.

The problem is, I need to import questions in bulk. Is this anyway possible?

Where does the plugin store the contents in db ?  Or maybe in filesystem?

Anything pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H5P has to use Moodle's File API and Moodle stores files in the Moodle data directory. This is a location on your server defined by you when you install Moodle. You can check the location of that directory in the Moodle config.php file. But the key thing is really that Moodle manages access to files via its File API and is not just storing files that can be retrieved. And the data directory should not be accessible via the web. So its practically impossible to access those files without [using the File API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_System_API).

This is a feature because it means that access to the files is managed by the same permissions system that controls access to pages on the Moodle site. So a student could not guess the URL of a file that they should not have access to. It also means that files associated with a course or activity can be backed up and restored with the course and activity.

Apart from that: Simply uploading files would not work. H5P performs a couple of actions when files are uploaded (validating the files, updating some database tables, possible installing missing libraries from the files, etc.), so the best approach would probably be to locate and use H5P's upload functions.